# oData binding to table generates repeated lines in table output

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

I have an OData connection using which I read an entityset with conditions that returns me data in the following structure. The data being in the root node itself rather than in an object array-

[oData Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7npVs.png)

I am then setting this data to a JSON Model and binding this model to my oTable.
The code in controller looks something like below-

```
//Get data for the table
var oTabData = sap.ui.getCore().byId("MyTable");
var sServiceUrl = "http://example.com/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZXX_SRV";
var oModel2 = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sServiceUrl,true);
var oJsonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel2.read("/MyEntitySet(Myvar1='000001',Myvar2='abc')?
$format=json",null,null,true,function(oData,response){  
        oJsonModel.setData(oData);
    });
oTabData.setModel(oJsonModel);
```

The view contains the table and the binding is as below. Have ignored rest of table declaration code to keep it short. Table declared as oTable with id MyTable and with all the right columns-

```
//Template to map the data to the respective column
var template = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
    id:"table_template",
    type: "Navigation",
    visible: true,
    cells:[
        new sap.m.Label({
            text: "{/Myvar1}"
        }),
        new sap.m.Label({
            text: "{/Myvar2}"
        }),
        new sap.m.Label({
            text: "{/Myvar3}"
        }),
        new sap.m.Label({
            text: "{/Myvar4}"
        })
    ]
});

var oFilters = null;
oTable.bindItems("/",template,null,oFilters);
```

The issues are-

1. As I have made a service call with conditions the oData output
   received does not output an array of data like it does when we make
   a call without conditions
   (`oModel2.read("/MyEntitySet?$format=json",null,null,true,function(oData,response)`).
   In the latter case the output comes under results array for which
   the binding assignment is /results and that works right as expected.
2. In current case (service call with conditions), as the columns in
   output are available right in the root level, have used binding **/**
   and in template as well using **/** in front of every element (e.g.
   `{/Myvar1}` as seen above). But using this technique it also creates 3
   default blank lines in table initially. When the above controller
   code is executed, it fills the table 3 x 4 times i.e. 12 rows for a
   single row output.

Due to organization restrictions I cannot put the original code here. But this is how the scenario is. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

PS: Haven't used any loop that would generate the repeated lines.

Comment: Why don't you use ODataModel2? Why don't you use odata list binding? This helps to get rid redundant intermediate JSON model. In addition, I believe that instead of "read" method call, you can bind the table directly to EntitySet with filters.

Comment: Hi Andrii,Thanks for your response. I am not much aware of v2 model, but I tried just by updating that line of code to refer to V2 model; but that did not work. If you can help with a working example of v2 model maybe I can then better and implement it correctly. Also, you said we we can bind the table directly to EntitySet; is it in case of v1 model itself? or is it the benefit of using v2?

Comment: Also, just to clarify better I haven't assigned any model binding to the table initially. Only after an action, in my case a dropdown change will update the table data using this call made through controller. Yet, initially the table gets 3 blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can **bind your table directly** to the ODataModel:

Steps:

1. Before doing binding, you need to create a **template for the table rows**, in sap.m.Table it is **ColumnListItem** control, I would suggest to carry it out to the **XML fragment**. Try to use XML for markup as much as possible, becasue it much clearer and maintainablier than js coding;
   All the controls in "cells" should be bound to the rows' properties using **relative paths**.
2. Tell the View about your model by calling "oView.setModel(MODEL_INSTANCE)", by this line you **set the default model to the view**. From now on all the controls inside are able to see it. The model is default because the name of it was not specified.
3. oTable.bindItems("/MyEntitySet", { template: oColumnListItem, filters: aFilters}); - this will **automatically trigger an OData call** to grab all needed data. The table will be updated automatically. You should see the rows.

Comment: Thanks for the details Andrii but I am already using template for table rows as seen in my code I posted. I haven't used XML views, can try it that way if that helps. Also the binding is done the same way you suggested. This can be seen in the code as well (oTable.bindItems("/",template,null,oFilters). About point 2, I did not get where to write this code.

Comment: I have noticed that only when I binditems at root level  oTable.bindItems("/",template,null,oFilters) then these multiple lines appear. Else when we get an array of data from service call in results object I use it like oTable.bindItems("/results",template,null,oFilters) and this does not create any issues. Initially the table remains blank and later when the call is made fills the data.

Comment: The point is that I suggest to solve your issue + make things in a proper way (to reduce complexity and amount of code lines and make solution maintainable).  With regards to your question, you can set model to view somewhere before you do "bindItems".